# product of ideals in matrix ring

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

It well known that if $R$ is a commutative ring then every ideal of $M_n(R)$ is $M_n (I)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$. My question is:
Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $M_n(R)$, i.e., $I=$M_n(A)$ and $J=$M_n(B)$. When is the statement $M_n(AB)=M_n(A)M_n(B)$ correct?

Comment: What you wrote is a tautology. Did you mean to ask if $M(AB)=M(A)M(B)$?

Comment: yes .. sorry for the misleading

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$ here ? Would these be ideals of $R$ ? If so then $AB \subset A$ and $AB \subset B$ by closure of ring multiplication on the ideal $A$  on the right and ideal $B$ on the left. Then $AB$ is a subset of the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are ideals of  a ring $R$ such that $A\subset B$ then, $M_n(A)\subset M_n(B)$. Therefore $M_n(AB)$ is a subset of the intersection of $M_n(A)$ and $M_n(B)$. Also, we can conclude that $M_n(A)M_n(B)\subset M_n(AB)$.  So, we are looking for when the intersection of $M_n(A)$ and $M_n(B)$ equal to the product of them.

Comment: @TurkiMohmd  *Therefore Mn(AB) is a subset of the intersection of $M_n(A)$ and $M_n(B)$. Also, we can conclude that $M_n(A)M_n(B)⊂Mn(AB)$.*  The first thing is correct, but it doesn't help you prove the second thing. Also, what is the use of assuming $A\subset B$? It doesn't make a lot of sense to do it by cases.

Answer (score 1):

The standard proof of the fact you mention makes use of the fact that if $J$ is an ideal of $M_n(R)$, then $J=M_n(I)$ where $I$ is the set of elements appearing in the upper left hand corner of elements of $J$.  That is what establishes the bijective and order preserving correspondence.

For $M_n(A)M_n(B)$, the ideal $I$ is clearly $AB$, so we’re already done.

Comment: Very nice solution.